# NextJS App Router redirect in react-hook-form

Tags: next.js, try-catch, next.js13, react-hook-form

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636460/nextjs-app-router-redirect-in-useeffect-hook). I have a login page, and the form checks if the email submitted has an account; if not, I want it to redirect to the register page:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const { email } = data;

  const res = await checkUser(email)
  .then(async (isUser) => {
    if (isUser) {
      // do proper authentication
    } else {
      redirect('/register'); 
    }
  })
}
```

The [only up-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637457/11020164) to that previous question says, "As far as I know, the `redirect` method is meant to be used on the server only," and then goes on to suggest using `useRouter`. Now, I could do that, but this is a NextJS 13 App-Router based app, and contrary to what was suggested in that answer, [the documentation says](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect), "`redirect` can be used in Server Components, Client Components, Route Handlers, and Server Actions." So, I feel like I should be using `redirect`.

Unfortunately, it `throw`s when it's called. Now, that behavior is documented as well, and is what it's supposed to do. But, instead of actually re-directing, it's being caught in my `catch` block.

A working (i.e., not working) example of the problem can be found in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-meninsky-cc73zw).

Although more verbose than the CodeSandbox demo of the problem, my actual code looks like this, with three different attempts (a, b, and c) mentioned in the comments:

```
const onSubmit = async (data, toast) => {

  const { email } = data;

  const res = await checkUser(email)
  .then(async (isUser) => {
    if (isUser) {
      const cb = await signIn('email', {
        email: email,
        callbackUrl: '/profile'
      });

      return cb;
    } else {
      redirect('/register'); // option a & b passes through to catch block below
      // throw new Error('NFU'); // option (c)
    }
  })
  .then((callback) => {
    if (callback?.error) {
      throw new Error(callback.error);
    } else if (callback?.ok) {
      toast.create({
        title: 'Congratulations!',
        description: `You're signed in!`,
        status: 'success',
        duration: 5000
      });

      // return true; // part of c, below
    }
  })
  .catch(((error) => {
    // option b, re-throw if we got a 404 from the checkUser call; 
    // unhandled runtime error
    if(isRedirectError(error)) throw error;
    // 
    // if ('NFU' === error.message) return false; // part of (c), below
    toast.create({
      title: 'Error',
      description: error.message,
      status: 'error',
      duration: 5000
    });
  }))

  // if (!res) redirect('/register') // option c, unhandled runtime error
}
```

In option (a), I just call `redirect`, which I assumed would work, but instead it gets caught in the `catch`. Option (b) came from [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49298#issuecomment-1537433377) on Vercel's GitHub from back in May, about using `redirect` in Server Actions. That was from before App Router left the experimental state, and what I'm doing isn't a server action; nevertheless, I thought I'd give it a try: simply re-`throw` the error from inside the `catch` if it's `isRedirectError`. But that results in Unhandled Runtime Error on the client, instead of redirecting.

Finally (option c), I tried removing the `redirect` from the promise chain entirely, setting `res` to either `true` or `false`, and then calling `redirect` if it's false; but that, too, results in an Unhandled Runtime Error.

How do I make this work?

For completeness sake, it may be worth noting that this `onSubmit` function is actually passed to [`handleSubmit`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/handlesubmit), as the form is managed by RHF.

Also, the `onSubmit` function is defined outside of the component, as the whole thing is wrapped in a [`FormProvider`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/formprovider) context where the `form` and `submit` button are different components that share the `onSubmit` code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem

Comment: Not really. I ended up just doing `router.push` instead of `redirect`. Works fine, but doesn't really seem in the spirit of the new, Right Way to do things.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it to work using server actions. Simply create a server action that calls `redirect` from `next/navigation` and call the function where you need it (even from client components). You can create a file called `actions.ts` and put the function in it.

```
'use server';

import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export async function navigate(url: string) {
    redirect(url);
}

...

import { navigate } from '@/app/actions';

navigate(`/signUpSuccess?email=${email}`);
```

This is also contained in the docs.